# Google Cloud Endpoints Internal Error response (500) with no logs

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

I've seen that sometimes the OPTIONS request fails with an internal error (500) but i can't see any logs regarding it on the log viewer. It fails before reaching my Cloud Endpoint implementation and i don't even know where to start looking for the possible cause.

Is there any known reason/cause that could generate an OPTIONS request to fail with an Internal Error?

Note: I'm using JAVA runtime.

Thanks.

Comment: this should work, i have used OPTIONS several times. Is this a constant behaviour in all your deployments/services or a sporadic bug once in a while?

Comment: Do you see a response body in the 500s? If you can log it, it would be helpful. We have an [external tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=Component=Endpoints&sort=-modified+-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log%20Modified) where you can file a bug (and this does sound like a bug). Just make sure to set Component to Endpoints.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @JCRamirez no and i'm no longer working with google cloud endpoints, sorry.